# Como carregar um axios url em src de image no Quasar/Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, quasar

Como eu carrego um axios no template de image src? Eu tentei dessa forma

```
<img :src="$axios.get(`/uploader/hotels/${hotel.photo}`)"/>
```

mas o resultado é um `[object Promise]` com retorno estranho:

```
http://localhost:8080/[object Promise]
```

Como removo o baseUrl do quasar para mostrar somente a url da api? O que esta faltando?

Eu gostaria de carregar diretamente na tag `src` de `img` sem precisar utilizar o `methods`. Pois assim eu poderia chamar o axios dessa forma em todas as páginas que fosse necessário.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que você esta utilizando o [cli.vuejs.org](https://cli.vuejs.org) para gerar seu projeto e fazer o build,
eu sugiro usar arquivos de variáveis de ambiente, [.env](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)

Imita a utilização de variáveis de ambiente do node.

Então você cria seus arquivos `.env` para seus ambientes(desenvolvimento, homologação e produção) com as variáveis:

```
NODE_ENV=development
VUA_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080/api
```

> VUE_APP_ é o prefixo obrigatório para as variáveis serem injetadas no seu app

E ai no seu código é só utilizar `process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL`

Ai ja não sei se é possível utilizar o `process.env.VUE_APP_X` em expressões no `<template>`, porém sugiro utilizar computed properties em seus componentes ou até criar um componente só para abstrair isso.

```
<template>
  <img :src="src" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Image',
  props: ['path'],
  computed: {
    src({ path }) {
      return `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL}/${path}`;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

E usa o componente:

```
<Image :path="`/uploader/hotels/${hotel.photo}`"/>
```

E no lugar onde você define o base url do axios, substitui por `process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL`.

Comment: Testei a primeira opção e não funciona em template como foi dito. Testei a segunda e a página fica travada. O principal motivo de eu querer usar dessa forma é porque no axios, já esta definido a url do server e só bastava concatenar com o local correspondente. Caso o sistema mude de servidor, eu mudaria em um só lugar. Acho que criar um componente só pra isso seria muito burocrático. Será se tem como eu definir uma variável do tipo string global em um local no quasar framework só pra acessar o endereço do server em qualquer lugar do sistema?

Comment: Calma, acho que agora eu entendi...
Você queria usar somente a url ja definida no axios como default.baseUrl para concatenar a url que colocou no src?
Ou vc quer chamar um serviço que uma url e finalmente usar a url retornada do serviço como src da imagem?

Comment: Somente a url resolve o problema. Estava pesquisando se tinha um local pra por essas variáveis assim eu poderia utilizar também no axios.

Comment: Certo, então você só precisa de usar a url... tranquilo, vou editar minha resposta

Comment: A solução proposta é interessante! Pois usou como base o .env que pode ser trocado facilmente para cada ambiente! Porem, achei estranho ter que refazer a tag img como component. Não seria mais interessante por o `process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL` direto no axios?

Comment: Sim, falei do componente de Image como exemplo. 
É que eu pessoalmente não acho interessante ficar usando o `$axios.defaults.baseURL`...
Eu ja iria partir para a estratégia de um componente especifico para abstrair esse trabalho de ficar colocando sempre o `process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL` ou criar uma função tipo `resolveImgSrc` e sempre usar ela para montar o  path.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui achar uma solução, o próprio Vuex tem uma variável global para acesso a url dentro do plugin axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://serverbackend:8765';

export default ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;
};
```

Logo a chamada na url ficou:

```
<img :src="`${$axios.defaults.baseURL}/uploader/hotels/${hotel.photo}`"/>
```

Problema resolvido :)